# Compiler ignore __stdcall

Tags: c++, visual-c++, calling-convention

It seems to me, that MSVS ignores __stdcall directive on my functions. I'm cleaning up the stack manually, but the compiler still append `ADD ESP` instructions after each `CALL`.

This is how I declare the function:

```
extern "C" void * __stdcall core_call(int addr, ...);
#define function(...) (DWORD WINAPI) core_call(12345, __VA_ARGS__)
return function("Hello", 789);
```

And this is how the output looks like:
[image]
<sub>(source: [server4u.cz](http://vs712.server4u.cz/msvs.png))</sub>

I've marked with arrows redundant `ADD` instructions, which MSVS automatically append after each call, despite the fact, that cleaining the stack is a callee responsibility (reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#List_of_x86_calling_conventions) and this causes the crash of my progrm. If I manually replace the `ADD` instructions with `NOPs`, program works as supposed. So, my question is... Is there a way how to force the compiler to stop addaing these instructions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is here: `, ...)`.

Functions with variable number of arguments cannot be `__stdcall`.

`__stdcall` functions must remove all their stack arguments from the stack at the end, but they can't know in advance how much stuff they will receive as parameters.

The same holds for `__fastcall` functions.

The only applicable calling convention for functions with variable number of arguments is `__cdecl`, where the caller has to remove the stack parameters after the call. And that's what the compiler uses despite your request to use `__stdcall`.

Comment: Do you know if a warning is generated when the compiler ignores the explicitly requested calling convention?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I spent few hours of debugging the code while I found out where the problem was. Compiler showed some warning, but it wasn't very clear to me why is it ignoring what I've explicitly assigned.
However, is there some workaround how to do this? I've even tried to write some inline assembly to pass arguments to function core_call, but I wasn't successful.

Comment: After few more hours of debugging, I've finally found out solution that works in MSVS. It's kind of nasty, but it works. http://pastebin.com/QmUQKm9S